# Closing Excel file opened with TCL\TK, using Python

Tags: python, excel

I have a Python script that interacts with some hardware using TCL\TK. It commands the hardware to perform some tests, and after generate an Excel report with some macros on it.
Since I'm performing several iterations of this test, I want to be able to close the Excel file between each iteration, within the Python script and not manually like I'm doing now.

Any suggestions?